# BadImageFormat error in debug mode (VS2010) after porting to windows7

Tags: c#

I have an application that works fine in Windows XP. I can debug, release etc. It also works fine in windows 7 but only release mode. If I attempt to debug, I get a BadImageformat error. The program calls a DLL and that is where it blows up. It complains about calling an unmanaged assembly but i'm not sure how (or why) I would need to change this DLL.

I have the source code to the DLL so I'm able to change it if necessary.

Thanks for any help!
--greg

Answer (score 1):

Do you run the same platform or is it x86 in XP and x64 in Windows 7 or vice versa ? Check if it is built correctly for 32-bit and 64-bit, and the runtime libraries it attempts to load are also the appropriate 32-bit or 64-bit dll's

Comment: This.  The Win 7 box is obviously running under x64 whereas the DLL is an x86 assembly.  The solution needs to have it's target set to x86.